# How do I find the cumulative distribution function of the sequence of random variables $X_n=(-1)^{n+X}+1/n$?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-limit-theorems

The related question is the following.

[image]

The solution is as follows.

[image]

I know that $$F_{X}(x)=P(X\leq x)=\begin{cases} 0, &x<-1 \\ 1/2, &x\in[-1,1) \\ 1, &x\geq 1\end{cases}.$$

But how do I find $F_{X_n}(x)=P(X_n\leq x)$?

Comment: From what book is this exercise?

Comment: @Masacroso Hi, it's just an exercise made up by my teacher I think. I've added the solution but it doesn't specifically state what $F_{X_n}(x)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $X_n = (-1)^{n+X}+\frac1n=(-1)^{n+1}+\frac1n$ since $X$ only takes value $1$ and $-1$.

That is $X_n$ is a deterministic quantity regardless of the value of $X$.

$P(X_n \leq t)=0$ if $t< (-1)^{n+1} + \frac1n$.

$P(X_n \leq t)=1$ if $t \geq (-1)^{n+1} + \frac1n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how I can now interpret from this that for $t<-1$, we have $P(X_n\leq t)=0$ (and for large enough $n$, we have  $P(X_n\leq t)=1/2$, etc.) as in the solutions in the original post? In other words how do I determine $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\leq t)$? It's not obvious to me because of the $(-1)^{n}$ term.

Comment: It is puzzling to me too. I don't see how $F_{X_n}$ takes value arbitrarily close to $\frac12$.